# Trazer dados e guardar numa variável no Controller - API Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

```
public function getListaPresencial(Request $request, Presencial $Presencial)
{
    if ($Presencial->id) {
        return response()->json(['data' => $Presencial->toArray()]);
    }

    $query = Presencial::query();
    $tipo = 1;
    $query->select('id', 'nome_professor', 'nome_disciplina', 'nome_curso', 'nome_turma', 'data_inicio');
 // $query->where('id','=',1 );
    $query->where('tipo','=',$tipo );
    $query->whereDate('data_inicio', date('Y-m-d'));

    return response()->json($query->paginate($request->get('limit')));

}
```

Preciso trazer o o resultado da pesquisa numa variavel:

**Exemplo:**

```
$nomeprofessor = ?
$nomedisciplina = ?
```

para eu poder gravar em outra tabela só esses dados.

Comment: Só para tirar a dúvida qual a versão do seu laravel?

Answer (score 0):

Acho que se você só quer alguns campos, seria melhor fazer um select somente pelos campos desejados:

```
$query->select('nomeprofessor');
$professores = $query->get();
$query->select('nomedisciplina');
$disciplinas = $query->get();
```

Comment: Provavelmente ele precisa de todos os que já tem, e precisa pegar alguns específicos para salvar em outra tabela

Comment: Exatamente isso, eu tenho 6 campos e preciso guardar em variáveis 4 deles para poder mandar para outra tabela.

Answer (score 0):

Aproveitei pra fazer uma melhoria de sintaxe no seu código, deixando mais padronizado.

Você já tem o resultado da sua pesquisa em `$query->paginate($request->get('limit'))` mas caso queira pegar todos sos valores da pesquisa sem paginação, você pode fazer:

```
public function getListaPresencial(Request $request, Presencial $Presencial)
{
    if ($Presencial->id) {
        return response()->json(['data' => $Presencial->toArray()]);
    }

    $tipo = 1; // não entendi porque não colocou isso diretamente na query, ma vamos manter

    $query = Presencial::select('id', 'nome_professor', 'nome_disciplina', 'nome_curso', 'nome_turma', 'data_inicio')
        ->where('id', '=', $tipo)
        ->whereDate('data_inicio', today());

    $presenciais = $query->get();
    dd($presenciais);

    return response()->json($query->paginate($request->get('limit')));

}
```

Assim a variável `$presenciais` vai ter os valores que você precisa.

O método `->get()` retorna uma `Collection` com todos os valores da busca então você pode trata-lo como uma [Collection](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods) no laravel.

Um exemplo de uso de uma *Collection* é:

```
$presenciais->each(static function ($presencial){
    $professor = $presencial->nome_professor;
    $disciplina = $presencial->nome_disciplina;
    // Agora você pode usar as variáveis "$professor" e "$disciplina" para salvar na outra tabela que você precisa

})
```

Comment: #perPage: 15
      +exists: true
      +wasRecentlyCreated: false
      #attributes: array:6 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "nome_professor" => "AVELAR TESTE DA SILVA"
        "nome_disciplina" => "TEST DE DISCIPLINA"
        "nome_curso" => "TESTE 1"
        "nome_turma" => "QUINTA SÉRIE"
        "data_inicio" => "2019-09-09"
      ]
      #original: array:

==> Como consigo separar cada resultado bnuma variavel?
$nome_disciplina = get(?) ?
sou novato e estou perdido, obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#available-methods tem as formas de se utilizar  uma Collection, se lembre que sua busca pode (e normalmente vai) trazer mais de um resultado, então você precisatratar cada resultado da sua colection, te recomento usar o `each()`

Comment: editei minha resposta